# Regex- Extract occurrence between to delimiters

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

How can I extract subsequent occurrence in this pattern:

```
123|xx3|1x23|1x2x3|x123x|123x
```

So for example I want to extract 3rd occurrence only, I've tried to use:

```
(?:.*?\\|){3}(.*)
```

But it extracts from 3rd occurrence and everything after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en#related_resources) reference shows an example of using a capturing group to extract the portion of a string you need.

So, match up to the 3rd part, and then capture the 3rd value:

```
^(?:[^|]*[|]){2}([^|]*)
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH6AWI/1), the green highlighted part will get extracted.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^|]*[|]){2}` - 2 occurrences of:

  - `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
  - `[|]` - a `|` pipe symbol
- `([^|]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `|`.